# Why is there a difference between floating-point multiplication with literals vs. variables in Go?

Tags: go, floating-point

Why are the following unequal in Go? Is this a bug, or is it by design? If it's by design, why does this occur and is this type of behavior documented anywhere?

https://play.golang.org/p/itEV9zwV2a

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    x := 10.1

    fmt.Println("x == 10.1:        ", x == 10.1)
    fmt.Println("x*3.0 == 10.1*3.0:", x*3.0 == 10.1*3.0)
    fmt.Println("x*3.0:            ", x*3.0)
    fmt.Println("10.1*3.0:         ", 10.1*3.0)
}
```

Produces:

```
x == 10.1:         true
x*3.0 == 10.1*3.0: false
x*3.0:             30.299999999999997
10.1*3.0:          30.3
```

Note that the same floating point math is being performed, just with different syntax. So why is the result different? I would expect `10.1*3.0` to equal `30.29999...` as in the `x*3.0` example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants and number literals in Go are untyped and have unlimited precision. The moment it has to be stored as a specific type, the bounds of that type apply. So when you declare `x := 10.1`, that literal is converted into a `float` and loses some precision. But when you specifically do `10.1*3.0` these have their full precision.

See the "Floats" header in this article. https://blog.golang.org/constants

> Numeric constants live in an arbitrary-precision numeric space; they
>   are just regular numbers. But when they are assigned to a variable the
>   value must be able to fit in the destination. We can declare a
>   constant with a very large value:
>
> ```
> const Huge = 1e1000
> ```
>
> —that's just a number, after all—but we can't assign it or even print it. This statement won't even compile:
>
> ```
> fmt.Println(Huge)
> ```
>
> The error is, "constant 1.00000e+1000 overflows float64", which is
>   true. But Huge might be useful: we can use it in expressions with
>   other constants and use the value of those expressions if the result
>   can be represented in the range of a float64.

How it actually does this, especially in the given `Huge` case, I do not know.

Comment: Interesting. This would make me expect that Go would throw a warning when a specific constant or literal cannot be expressed precisely in a `float64` (like 10.1 or .1), the same as if a huge number overflows an int or float type. I.e. 10.1 cannot truly "fit" in a `float64`, or a float of any length. Perhaps there was a design decision not to do this because the warnings would be so common.

Comment: The compiler stores them as `big.Float`s (or `big.Int`s or `big.Rat`s), unsurprisingly. Remember, the Go compiler is written in Go :)

Comment: BTW: the closest [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) to 10.1 is 10.100000381...

Answer (score 3):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do
>   not overflow. Consequently, there are no constants denoting the
>   IEEE-754 negative zero, infinity, and not-a-number values.
>
> Implementation restriction: Although numeric constants have arbitrary
>   precision in the language, a compiler may implement them using an
>   internal representation with limited precision. That said, every
>   implementation must:
>
> - Represent integer constants with at least 256 bits.
> - Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a
>     complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed
>     binary exponent of at least 16 bits.
> - Give an error if unable to represent an integer constant
>     precisely.
> - Give an error if unable to represent a floating-point or complex
>     constant due to overflow.
> - Round to the nearest representable constant if unable to represent
>     a floating-point or complex constant due to limits on precision.
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> A numeric type represents sets of integer or floating-point values.
>   The predeclared architecture-independent floating-point numeric types
>   are:
>
> ```
> float32     the set of all IEEE-754 32-bit floating-point numbers
> float64     the set of all IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point numbers
> ```

---

Constants use package [`math/big`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/) at compile time for arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Variables use [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), which is often provided by the hardware, for floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks. This also specifically explains that the compiler should not throw a warning or error if the it is unable to represent a floating-point constant *due to limits on precision* (but will throw an error in the case of overflow).